# how to check access token made by go middleware using javascript?

Tags: javascript, go

I need to change some buttons on my UI depend on whether a user is authorized or not. To do this I need to check the access token. I made my server using Gin. This is my routes:

```
router := gin.Default() 

router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
router.Static("static/", "./static/")

router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Главная страница"})
})

router.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Главная страница"})
})

router.GET("/users", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "register.html", gin.H{"title": "Регистрация"})
})

router.POST("/users", server.createUser, func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Регистрация"})
})

router.GET("/login", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "auth.html", gin.H{"title": "Авторизация"})
})
router.POST("/login", server.loginUser, func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Главная страница"})
})

authRoutes := router.Group("/").Use(authMiddleware(server.tokenMaker))

authRoutes.GET("/account/:username", server.getUser, func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "account.html", gin.H{"title": "Личный кабинет"})
})

router.Run()
```

This is my middleware:

```
const (
    authorizationHeaderKey  = "authorization"
    authorizationTypeBearer = "bearer"
    authorizationPayloadKey = "authorization_payload"
)

func authMiddleware(tokenMaker token.Maker) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        authorizationHeader := ctx.GetHeader(authorizationHeaderKey)
        fmt.Println("header:", authorizationHeader)
        if len(authorizationHeader) == 0 {
            err := errors.New("authorization header is not provided")
            ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }
        fields := strings.Fields(authorizationHeader)
        if len(fields) < 2 {
            err := errors.New("invalid authorization header format")
            ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }

        authorizationType := strings.ToLower(fields[0])
        if authorizationType != authorizationTypeBearer {
            err := fmt.Errorf("unsupported authorization type %s", authorizationType)
            ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }

        accessToken := fields[1]
        payload, err := tokenMaker.VerifyToken(accessToken)
        if err != nil {
            ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, errorResponse(err))
            return
        }

        ctx.Set(authorizationPayloadKey, payload)
        ctx.Next()
    }
}
```

So my question is how to check if the user is authorized or not using javascript? How to pass a token to the js? Where to call it, how to implement it?

If you need to see my html templates, ask me and I'll update this question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you render the template, you know if the user is authorized or not. Simply use a flag when you are rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to implement token-based authentication. First is using Auth header (like what you are trying to do), and second is using cookies.

To use the Auth header, when the user (Frontend) has successfully logged in (correct username/email and password combination), send a response with the token in the body. The frontend (JavaScript) can take that token and store it in `localStorage`. From then on, every time the frontend sends request to the backend, put that token in the request header. With this method, the frontend can check whether or not a token is present in the `localStorage` to determine if the user is authenticated. Now, anyone can create a token in localStorage on their browser. However, when the frontend attempts to use that fake token to authenticate, the backend middleware should verify that token and respond with a `401` code.

To use cookies, after a successful login, the backend will `setCookie` on the frontend. The frontend does not have to be involved in this process. Every time a request is made, the Auth header is not checked; instead, the backend `getCookie`, checks if the cookie with the name exists, and verifies the token in that cookie. To check if the user is authenticated in the frontend, the backend can send a piece of information back in the response body to the frontend and have it stored in the `localStorage`. This part is mainly up to you to implement since there are many ways you approaches you could take.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! generally I understand how it works. but I don't know how to implement it technically. can you please share with me an example of code if you have?